# Rails testing against a legacy database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a huge problem. I've started to integrate tests into my rails application. It's an admin system for an existing database. The application works really well and everything is in place to deal with this but since I've decided to use `rspec` the testing database is messed up.

Whenever I run: `rake db:test:clone` (I want to clone the current database to keep data etc) I get a mysql error:

`Invalid default value for 'active'`

Which in the schema has this:

`t.string  "active",  limit: 0, default: "Yes", null: false`

The problem is `limit:0`. There are ~50 fields that have this `limit:0` against them and I'm pretty sure they are all enums/sets. What's the way to fix this?

Comment: It seems as you have not proper workflow for a testing. You do not need clone database (rspec do it automaticly) also you do not need to copy records to testing database (it does with FactoryGirl) I think you should start from here http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test

Comment: No, I do. It's a legacy database. It contains 1000s of records such as categories etc that the testing system needs

Comment: Legacy db is used for development not for testing.

Comment: Yes, I am aware. But the application does not *work* without the legacy database. You cannot test an application that does not work. I know what you're saying, but in this situation you are wrong.

Comment: Is the test database also mysql? Just a thought that you might have forgotten to change from sqlite in the database.yml?

Comment: Yep, it's MySQL2. It works if I build the database manually and migrate on my own. But I want to just be able to run the tests using the above command to wipe all test data afterwards

Comment: I think what @itsnikolay says is that you shouldn't depend on an existing db, but construct a minimum working set from your test suite.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. The solution is to just clone the development database and then work from there. I can't build 10s of 1000s of records using seeds. Sure it's not an ideal situation, but it's a legacy system and I'm building around it. I would like to just be able to build the database from scratch but I can't.

Comment: Mhhh, the problem is that every test should not be aware of data in another test, that's why you want an "empty" database on each spec. If you relay on data in database, think about a simple test as Opportunity.save (let's immagine is false) Opportunity.scoped.should be_empty won't pass. Is the legacy DB readonly? If that's the case, it's ok.

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you use [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl)?

Even for a legacy database you must be able to model your Models with a Factory and sequences should give you enough uniqueness to create multiple records at spec run. If you can't, then you have a bigger problem than recreating your test database each run and should address that first.

Most likely you are trying to use the actual data, because you feel it best represents randomness and trueness in your data. But I doubt it's stress testing your code enough. eg. you can utilize the [FFaker](https://github.com/EmmanuelOga/ffaker) gem to create a paragraph

```
Faker::Lorem.paragraph(1000)
```

That would test your databases' text fields.

```
# contrived factory example spec/factories/contrived_example_factory.rb
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :contrived_example do 
    description Faker::Lorem.paragraph(1000)
  end
end
```

Now you can you hammer your database with multiple records and you might find that your database can't handle it. Better to find this out in testing than in production.

If you use FactoryGirl's let syntax you won't be creating things unless they're needed. (although remember that with the let syntax the thing in the let block doesn't exist until you actually call it.) Once you've setup the factory you can create a list of data from your factory with #create_list

```
# In ContrivedExample Spec
let(:one_hundred_things) {FactoryGirl.create_list :your_factory_name_here, 100}

# And then Sample 1 item to use in your unit tests or integration tests. 
let(:one_thing) {one_hundred_things.sample)

# in unit test
it("saves") {expect(one_thing.save).to be_true}

# in integration test
it("#show") do                                                                                                                    
  get :show, id: one_thing.id                                                                                                        
  expect(assigns(:contrived_example)).to eq one_thing                                                                                           
end
```

Combine this with Database Cleaner gem and you can start fresh after every test. Combine it with Spork and you'll leverage dRB in your testing, which should speed it up with the added benefit of testing thread-ability. :)

Also as @xlembouras points out setting limit: 0 will set your varchars to 0. Probably not what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant answer. I've tried using factory girl but there are whole tables that are needed for the application to run correctly and there's hundreds of records so it'll take a long time to build all that with factory girl

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it there are two problems you have to resolve.

Firstly and (**IMHO**) most severe is the fact that you need a full database to test your application. That is a serious indication of previous wrong design decisions.

Secondly (and more in your problem) you seem to have an inconsistency in your db.
I might be mistaken but I think `limit: 0` is an invalid option. (I thought that `limit` on a string shows the length of `varchar`, but I am not confident about it).

As a workaround you could try to use `rake db:test:prepare` instead of clone.

Comment: `Firstly and (IMHO) most severe is the fact that you need a full database` - Sure, that's correct. It wasn't my decision though. It's a backend for an existing application that's been going 4 years strong. The `limit:0` seems to be on ENUM fields